# Multiple Nested Random Effects affecting a Mixed Model

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, random-effects-model, nested-data, nested-models

I have a quite complex psychophysiological data dependant of different nested data in a repeated measures experiment.

The first nested structure comes from the data collection were there are several blocks containing several trials with 3 repetitions per trial. The second comes from grouping as we are measuring the adjustment in a particular task between a pair of participants in this repetitions of the same trial.

I'd like to do various measurements within pair of subjects but I always end up having the same constraint with the nested data.

The result of not having a good structured data makes the models I try to fit have enormous amounts of df wich consequently make me having irrelevant models (that explain only a ridiculous amount of variability).

Logic tells me it should be nested by random effects twice:

```
(1|CoupleID/SubjectID) <- Regarding the nesting of the subjects
(1|Block/Trial/TrialRep) <- Regarding at what point in the experiment was the response data collected
```

Therefore, this would be some of the models I would be interested in to be served as an example, so I can relate a particular response to a behavioural measurement:

```
1. lmer(electrode_response~TrialRep)
2. lmer(electrode_response~divergence_withinparticipants)
3. lmer(electrode_response~participant_adjustment)
```

The random effects term I am trying looks like this:

```
lmer(electrode_response~TrialRep+(TrialRep |SubjectID)+(1|CoupleID/SubjectID)+(1|Block/Trial/TrialRep)
```

Which a priori could look like it gives a good explanation:

```
Linear mixed model fit by REML. t-tests use Satterthwaite's method ['lmerModLmerTest']
Formula: electrode_response ~ TrialRep + (TrialRep | SubjectID) + (1 | CoupleID/SubjectID) + (1 | Block/Trial/TrialRep)
   Data: finaldb
Control: lmerControl(optimizer = "optimx", optCtrl = list(method = "nlminb"))

REML criterion at convergence: 80726

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-5.3489 -0.5861  0.0203  0.6204  6.7150 

Random effects:
 Groups                 Name        Variance  Std.Dev. Corr 
 TrialRep:(Trial:Block) (Intercept)   0.82127  0.9062       
 Trial:Block            (Intercept)   0.05282  0.2298       
 SubjectID:CoupleID     (Intercept)   9.21819  3.0361       
 SubjectID              (Intercept)  19.82985  4.4531       
                          TrialRep    3.16028  1.7777  -1.00
 CoupleID               (Intercept)   2.03290  1.4258       
 Block                  (Intercept)   0.08479  0.2912       
 Residual                           100.53917 10.0269       
Number of obs: 10800, groups:  TrialRep:(Trial:Block), 300; Trial:Block, 100; SubjectID:CoupleID, 36; SubjectID, 36; CoupleID, 18; Block, 4

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error      df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   8.5483     0.9857 24.1529   8.672 6.98e-09 ***
TrialRep     -1.8157     0.3254 37.6691  -5.581 2.20e-06 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
         (Intr)
```

As you can see I'm using an optimizer, but even with this I often, in the data collected in some electrodes, can find the subsequent warnings, even though I use the same nesting structure in the data:

```
boundary (singular) fit: see ?isSingular
Warning message:
In optwrap(optimizer, devfun, getStart(start, rho$lower, rho$pp),  :
  convergence code 1 from optimx
```

Or

```
Warning messages:
1: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  unable to evaluate scaled gradient
2: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model failed to converge: degenerate  Hessian with 1 negative eigenvalues
3: Model failed to converge with 1 negative eigenvalue: -7.8e-01
```

Wich I fail to comprehend. Also, the Rsq I get with `r.squaredGLMM()` of `MuMIn` package tells me not a lot is explained by my model.

```
> r.squaredGLMM(electrode_response)
            R2m       R2c
[1,] 0.01769641 0.1905829
```

I would really appreciate some feedback on this matter, I have gone out of ideas.

Comment: Try removing `Block` from the random structure and fit it as a fixed effect. Alternatively, or perhaps as well, try removing `TrialRep` as a random slope. You might also try using the `GLMMadaptive` package instead of `lme4`

Comment: First of all, thanks for the input `@RobertLong` , I started doing what you suggested on removing the Block from the random nest structure and fitting it to the fixed effects and the model didn't converge warning with negative eigenvalues. Then I followed the suggestion of removing `TrialRep` as a random slope and it worked just fine, even though Rsq did not substantially get better. At last, I tried `GLMMadaptive` but I think I could not figure out how to fix two nested random structures looking at the documentation, I'm sorry I am not a statistician and probably is me not using it properly.

Comment: I also tried putting everything transformed into Z scores but contrary to my beliefs, it did not affect the output. At the end, I ended up using the theoretical logic, I studied a mixed model tutorial [http://bodowinter.com/tutorial/bw_LME_tutorial2.pdf] that really helped me understand better the basis of it and I ended up, even though with a poor explaining of my variability, with these models:

Comment: 1. `lmer(electrode_response ~  TrialRep + (1+TrialRep|CoupleID/SubjectID)`  2. `lmer(electrode_response ~  participant_adjustment + (1+participant_adjustment|ID/AbsSuj) + (1+participant_adjustment|Trial_all/TrialRep)`  3.  `lmer(electrode_response ~  divergence_withinparticipants + (1+divergence_withinparticipants|ID/AbsSuj) + (1+divergence_withinparticipants|Trial_all/TrialRep)`

Comment: I tested with and without the slope model and made an ANOVA on both fits and even though it was not significantly different I ended up with what I think is, for now at least, the most accurate expression of my experimental design.